# Flexirest to handle string array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm using Flexirest to make a request to an endpoint that returns an array of strings with `Content-Type: application\json`.

This is the model:

```
class Neighborhood < BaseModel
  get :by_location, "/neighborhoods/by_location"
end
```

And this is how I make the request:

```
def get_neighborhood_list
  city_to_use = ApplicationHelper.user_location[:city] || Rails.configuration.default_location[:city]
  @hoods = Neighborhood.by_location(city: city_to_use)
end
```

And this is called but it only reaches the `super` line since it breaks inside there:

```
def handle_response(response, cached = nil)
  result = super(response, cached)
  setup_paging_variables result, response
  setup_paging_variables result.data, response if result.respond_to? 'data'
  result
end
```

The endpoint returns an array of strings:

```
[
    "Ahwatukee Foothills Village",
    "Alhambra",
    "Camelback East Village",
    "Central City",
]
```

With this headers

[image]

My problem is that Flexirest is treating the strings as json objects instead due to the value on the `Content-Type` header.
I get this error

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

on this line on the `if attributes[:_links]`.
It's getting there because `hal_response?` is true

Do I need to do something in particular in order for Flexirest to stop behaving like this?

---

**Update**

I guess I didn't explained it properly. The error is occurring on the gem side.
Here is the full error:

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:612:in `handle_hal_links_embedded'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:553:in `new_object'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:704:in `block in generate_new_object'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:703:in `generate_new_object'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:501:in `handle_response'
  config/initializers/01_flexirest.rb:7:in `handle_response'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in call'
  faraday (0.9.2) lib/faraday/response.rb:57:in `on_complete'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:200:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/request.rb:156:in `call'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/mapping.rb:46:in `_call'
  flexirest (1.5.5) lib/flexirest/mapping.rb:28:in `block in _map_call'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:93:in `get_neighborhood_list
```

The `if attributes[:_links]` line is part of the gem code, and it's [here on this line](https://github.com/flexirest/flexirest/blob/master/lib/flexirest/request.rb#L662)

When it reaches this line the value of `attributes` is one of the strings inside the response, for instance: `attributes = "Ahwatukee Foothills Village"`. That's why it gives the error.

**What I'm trying to figure out if there is a way (maybe something in the configuration) that I can use Flexirest to handle this kind of responses.**

Comment: can you show more code?

Comment: @ArupRakshit there isn't much more code for that request, I don't have access to the backend

Comment: ok.. where is the line `if attributes[:_links]`?

Comment: I think your problem lies in `if attributes[:_links]`, I bet `attributes` has what Flexirest gives you, and if you see, it is an array. So, trying to access an array(`attributes`) by using a symbol(`:_links`) will indeed give you that error. To illustrate that, try in your console `a = [1,2,3]`, then `a[:_links]` and you'll get `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`. So, I'll suggest to look at Flexirest and see how you can access the whole response, because it looks like that's what you want.

Comment: @ArupRakshit that line is part of the gem code, I have updated the question with the error stack and the link to the line.

Comment: @fanta yes, the error is occuring for that reason (I have updated the question with more info) but the problem is that all this is done on the gem side.

Comment: @moondaisy from controller I see you call method `get_neighborhood_list`. What is the implementation of this?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I updated the question, it fails when making the call (second line of that method)

Comment: When it is an hal response, it expects the attribute to be present and response should be different structure also.. as per my reading.. I am still reading their code..

Comment: @moondaisy This gem is built for this https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08 .. I don't think it will work with yours one.. Check Response https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08#section-3

Comment: as @ArupRakshit said, the gem won't work in your case because the response you're getting back is not in the format Flexirest is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question but thought I'd answer it. you need to add

> plain: true

in your model like below.

```
class Neighborhood < BaseModel
  get :by_location, "/neighborhoods/by_location", plain: true
end
```

It will then return the string array